# Questions about Net Native

Tags: visual-studio, .net-native

I have some questions about `Net Native`:

1. Can I compile a `windows form application` with it?
2. Is compiled file independent of `.Net Framework`?can I Run in `Windows XP` that is not installed `.Net Framework`?
3. For using of that, must Visual Studio 2015 installed?
4. Is this only way for Native compile ?

Comment: 1: No.  Surely the rest is irrelevant.

Comment: how can i do @HansPassant to have a native assembly without MSIL codes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET Native is only for UWP apps at the moment. These apps can only be built with VS2015 RTM and with the "Tools for Universal Windows Apps" (release date July 29th). They can only run on Windows 10 devices.

When you build a UWP app with .NET Native then yes it is completely independent of the system-wide install of .NET. Indeed .NET UWP apps will run fine even on Windows 10 devices that don't have .NET installed.